# C++ Object Composition and Separate Compilation

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, header-files, composition

When I write C++ code I often try to limit the amount of header files that I have to `#include`, because it keeps compilation time smaller and also prevent unnecessary recompilation of compilation units when part of my program changes.

On the other hand I also try to avoid managing the memory myself, and I prefer to use `Object x;` instead of `std::uniq_ptr<Object> x(new Object)` or `Object *x`. But doing so implies that I have knowledge of the `Object`'s definition with the appropriate `#include` in my header, as in the example below:

```
    // Resources.h

    #include <...> /* Include the header files needed to build an instance of Resources.
    There quite be quite a lot of them, like some templated libraries, stuff that calls
    upon some OpenGL functions, and so on. */

    class Resources {
        Rectangle      rect;
        Matrix<double> mat;
        ImagePNG       img;

    public:
        Resources(... /* give some parameters to initialize the resources */);
    }
```

And now in another part of the program I have something like this:

```
    // Application.h

    #include "Resources.h" // <-- I want to get rid of this line

    class Application {
        Resources res;

    public:
        Application(... /* some parameters */);
    }
```

So, as you can see, I would like to remove the line `#include "Resources.h`. I know about forward declaration and I imagine I could do something like this:

```
    // Application.h

    class Resources;

    class Application {
        Resources *res;

    public:
        Application(... /* some parameters */);
    }
```

But now my problem is how to manage the memory? I don't really want to be forced to write my own custom destructor/copy constructor/assignment operator every time I want to use a pointer instead of the whole object. And if I copy my instance of `Application`, I want a full copy of `res` to be created as well (so a `std::shared_ptr<Resources>` wouldn't do: this is really object composition).

So I was wondering if anyone could give some advice in this kind of situation?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the [pimpl idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill04.htm)

Comment: Write your own smart pointer template that copies the pointed-to object. I wonder why there's no standard component like this, it's very handy.

Comment: Andrew: But then I would have to manually define the whole destructor/copy constructor/assignment operator and this is tedious. So I was wondering if it could be automated somehow.

Comment: You may use interface, and so hide member of the classes and you may also hide concrete classes completely inside a .cpp .

Comment: @Jarod42 OP wants to copy objects around without worrying about memory management. This is not so convenient with interfaces.

Comment: I think I may end up writing a smart pointer like n.m. suggested. It is surprising indeed that no such thing already exists.